# Liquibase inserting into BIT column, MySQL, data too long for column

Tags: java, liquibase

In Liquibase, I define a table with a column of type BIT(1)

```
<changeSet author="foobar" id="create-configuration-table">
    <createTable tableName="configuration">
        <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT(19)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" />
        </column>
        <column name="active" type="BIT(1)" />
        <column name="version" type="INT(10)" />
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

In the subsequent changeset, I want to insert data into this table, however, when inserting data into the 'active' column of type BIT(1), MySQL complains 'Data truncation: Data too long for column'

I have tried:

```
<insert>
   <column name="active" value="1" type="BIT(1)" />
</insert>
```

and

```
<insert>
   <column name="active" value="1"/>
</insert>
```

and

```
<insert>
   <column name="active" value="TRUE" type="BOOLEAN"/>
</insert>
```

What is the correct way to insert into a BIT(1) column?

Comment: there is an [open issue](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1991) on that

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Answering my own question as I figured this out right after I posted it. To insert into a BIT(1) column, you need to define the value as `valueBoolean`

```
<insert>
   <column name="active" valueBoolean="true"/>
</insert>
```

Comment: I had similar problem with data load from CSV. If data is loaded from CSV <loadData> node should declare field as  <column name="active" type="boolean" />, and values in CSV should be true/false

Answer (score 13):

There is a similar case when loading records per table from csv files with `<loadData>`.
In the `<loadData>` element, you have to explicitly specify type for each Boolean columns in the table:

```
<loadData encoding="UTF-8"
          file="path/to/file.csv"
          separator=","
          tableName="MY_TABLE"
>
    <!-- specify that values in my_boolean_column should be interpreted as Boolean values -->
    <column name="my_boolean_column" type="BOOLEAN" />
</loadData>
```

Hope it helps other folks who landed here having trouble with this.

Comment: It didn't work for me. Liquibase still tries to insert '1' into the column.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was using loadData instead of insert, and I had to use the following:

```
<column name="active" type="boolean"/>
```

Comment: To indicate that the value to be inserted is a bit (or multiple bits) Mysql and MariaDB use the notations:
    
    b'0' respectively b'1'

or for multiple bits e.g.

    b'00100110'

Answer (score 0):

In my case with MariaDB it had to be:

```
<column name="show_in_app_directory" type="bit" valueBoolean="true" />
```

Leaving out 'type="bit"' as suggested by dustin.schultz I get a Liquibase validation error:

```
column 'type' is required for all columns
```